# How to combine all pages from API into one JSON response with python?

Tags: python, pagination, get

I am stuck trying to make a loop that goes through all the pages of an API response and combines them into one output, preferably a dataframe. I replaced any API info with the test information they provide.

First I set up my basic imports, etc. with this:

```
# Dependencies and Setup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import json

# Create a cleaned json response
def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)

# Define variables
access_token = "xxx"
base_url = "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData"
endpoint = "/test/Property/replication"
url = base_url+endpoint
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}

# Set query parameters (I limit this to 10 records just to make sure the request works)
payload={
  '$filter': "PropertyType eq 'Residential' and StandardStatus eq 'Closed' and PropertySubType ne 'Single Family Residence' and PropertySubType ne 'Townhouse'",
  '$top': 10
    }

# Make get request
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

# Print first page of results
jprint(response.json())
```

I get this in the body of the response:

```
{
@odata.context: "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/$metadata#Property",
@odata.nextLink: "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property/replication?$next=1587765844387b617316828687dcd8f60d9e7d72efcc1",
@odata.count: 6550,
value: [
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...},
{...}
]
```

The @odata.nextLink url takes me to the second page of the results, with the same @odata.nextLink url except it changes the $next='xxx' to another seemingly random set of numbers  and letters.

Comment: dude don't add token in post

Comment: It’s a junk token. It’s the same one for everyone to access the test set

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `while` loop that loops until there are no more `@odata.nextLink`'s in the returned json. You can extend a list with all the data in `['value']`, which will result in a list with 27 items in this case:

```
# Dependencies and Setup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import json

# Create a cleaned json response
def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)

# Define variables
access_token = "6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21"
base_url = "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData"
endpoint = "/test/Property/replication"
url = base_url+endpoint
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}

# Set query parameters (I limit this to 10 records just to make sure the request works)
payload={
  '$filter': "PropertyType eq 'Residential' and StandardStatus eq 'Closed' and PropertySubType ne 'Single Family Residence' and PropertySubType ne 'Townhouse'",
  '$top': 10
    }

# Make get request
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
response_data = response.json()

#create list to store the values
data = []
data.extend(response_data['value'])

while True:
  response = requests.request("GET", response_data['@odata.nextLink'], headers=headers, data=payload)
  response_data = response.json()
  if '@odata.nextLink' in response_data.keys():
    data.extend(response_data['value'])
  else:
    break
```

Comment: Do you know how I would save that into a pandas dataframe without all the brackets etc.? I was successful in getting it into a csv file but I would like to strip the brackets and other json formatting.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`. Then you can export to csv `df.to_csv('filename.csv)`