# Python API call pagination issue

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am stuck on the following issue: I have the code below for an API call. In and of itself, the API call is fine, no server issues, I have checked it in Postman:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/$metadata#Orders",
    "value": [
        {....}
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Orders?refresh_token=xxx&$skip=100"
}
```

I am new to all of this, so please bear with me. All I want to do is save all of the records into a data frame at the end, not just the first 100 records. Channel Advisor's documentation is not really helpful, either, and I haven't been able to find what I need when searching on Google.

[I found a post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754620/how-to-combine-all-pages-from-api-into-one-json-response-with-python) that I massaged to add on the "while" loop, and I had to modify it to fit my requirements.

**Code version 1 (full):**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

def get_access_token():
    url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxx'}
    post_body = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': 'xxxxx'}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_body)
    return response.json()['access_token']

access_token = get_access_token()

url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/orders'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token,
    'accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response_data = response.json()['value']
response_nextlink = response.json()['@odata.nextLink']

#create list to store the values
data = []
data.extend(response_data)

while True:
    if '@odata.nextLink' in response_nextlink:
        response = requests.request('GET', response_data['@odata.nextLink'], headers=headers)
        response_data = response.json()['value']
        data.extend(response_data['value'])
        response_nextlink = response.json()['@odata.nextLink']
    else:
        break
```

This code only runs once, likely because the while loop is not set up correctly.

So, I added some error handling:

**Code version 2:**

```
while True:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Error occurred. Status code: ", response.status_code)
        print("Content: ", response.content)
        break
    response_data = response.json().get('value')
    if not response_data:
        break
    data.extend(response_data)
    if '@odata.nextLink' in response.json():
        url = response.json()['@odata.nextLink']
    else:
        break
```

The result of this is a Status code 400 runtime error. Again, the server is fine when I try the call on Postman.

So, I modified the while loop again:

**Code version 3:**

```
while True:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response_data = response.json()['value']
    data.extend(response_data)
    if '@odata.nextLink' in response.json():
        url = response.json()['@odata.nextLink']
    else:
        break
```

This produces the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [80], in <cell line: 25>()
     24 while True:
     25     response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
---> 26     response_data = response.json()['value']
     27     data.extend(response_data)
     28     if '@odata.nextLink' in response.json():

...................

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am otherwise stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I dont have API access I can only guess that you confused the break condition in the while loop

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

# start session to store cookies / authentications
s = requests.Session()

url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxx'}
post_body = {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': 'xxxxx'}
response = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_body)
access_token = response.json()['access_token']

url = 'https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/orders'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token,
    'accept': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# use session for requests
response = s.get(url, headers=headers)

# parse response only once
json_response = response.json()

response_data = json_response['value']


#create list to store the values
data = []
data.extend(response_data)

while True:
    if '@odata.nextLink' in json_response:
        response = s.request('GET', json_response['@odata.nextLink'], headers=headers)
        print("request returned status", response.status_code, response.text)
        if not response.ok:
            break
        json_response = response.json()
        data.extend(json_response["value"])
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried out your code, and I get this error:

Comment: `....---> 34 response = requests.request('GET', response_data['@odata.nextLink'],
 headers=headers)

     35 json_response = response.json()

     36 data.extend(json_response["value"])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Sorry about the formatting; I tried mini markdown, but this is what came out.

Comment: From what I understand, and that's as far as I got, `response_data = json_response['value']` sets that variable to, well, the second part of the json response here: `{
    "@odata.context": "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/$metadata#Orders",
    "value": [
        {....}
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/Orders?refresh_token=xxx&$skip=100"
}`
But that part does not have the `response_data['@odata.nextLink']` information in it.

Comment: Oh, my bad, there was one wrong line. I updated my code accordingly...

Comment: No worries. :) You're trying to help, and that is very much appreciated. I'll try the code out soon and give you feedback.

Comment: I tried out your code and this line in the `while` loop throws an error: `json_response = response.json()`. The error message is: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. Within the Traceback is this block: `UnicodeDecodeError: Wrong UTF codec detected; usually because it's not UTF-8but some other 8-bit codec.  This is an RFC violation, and the server didn't bother to tell us what codec *was* used.` That part is precisely where I got stuck myself and couldn't get past it. Any ideas?

Comment: i updated a few lines that might help you find the error. Maybe you can post the result again?

Comment: The revised `while` loop now returns this response: `request returned status 400`.

Comment: I updated a line to output the error text

Comment: This is the "pretty" response: `Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.` The rest of it talks about how to make a custom error page. BTW, when I click on the link in Postman at the bottom of the JSON response and then send the new request, I get an "authorization has been denied" error.

Comment: i have an idea, one moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252488/discussion-between-dolunaykiz-and-klops).

Comment: Update: @klops code works with a different endpoint, so I am assuming that the errors I am seeing are related to the server itself.